# Efficient algorithm: $(y+1)^n$

Tags: algorithms, natural-numbers

Given $y,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and knowing the value $y^n$, is there an efficient way to calculate $(y+1)^n$? Anything faster than the binomial theorem is welcome.

Comment: As $16=2^4$, given $16$ you'd get the answer $3^4=81$. As $16=4^2$, given $16$ you'd get the answer $5^2=25$. So, if you know $y^n=16$, what's $(y+1)^n$ again?

Comment: I can't find the relationship

Comment: A hint would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, that the knowledge of $y^n$ cannot speed up $O(\log n)$ algorithm of [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Binomial theorem will give you $O(n)$ at best.

Comment: True, the binomial theorem is terrible.. But I need to use the value y^n somehow. Maybe my teacher is making fun of us.